# I keep getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function find () {

  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cal-0");
  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let i = 1999

  for(i = 1999; i < 2005; i++){
    if (data[i][1] === ""){
      break;
    } 
    Logger.log('W0:' + data[i][0])
  };
}
```

I have found that it is a problem of how I write it, of how I initiate the array data but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The error means that for some `i`, `data[i]` is `undefined`. You can avoid the error by checking to see if the value is `undefined` before attempting to access a property.

Comment: @Pointy thank you for the help, I did it, it was exactly that

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this script, find the last row?

Comment: As for how to fix, probably your sheet has less than 2005 (or 1999) rows. That is why you're getting the error when you're trying to get the rows from 1999 to 2005. Are you sure that you have over 1999 rows?

Comment: why did not you include the sheet fragment (image) to see your data exactly? I mean the range Cal-0!A2000:B2005, It is important for clarification.